# Big O for a nested series of for loops

Tags: java, big-o, performance

I've got a question about calculating Big O running times for a series of loops, that are nested in an outer for loop.

For example:

```
for (50,000 times)
{
    for (n times)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    for (n-2 times)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    for (n times)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    for (n-2 times)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The outer loop is a constant, so I think that is ignored. Is it then as easy as doing the following calculation?

N + N-2 + N + N-2

2N + 2(N-2)

4N - 4

O(4N - 4)

O(4N) - after removing the -4 constant

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is correct, but you have another constant to remove: O(4n) is just O(n).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is O(n)

(you are only interested in what is the "largest" part of the equation, and you strip the constant).

If you had a loop *i* from 1..n and another loop inside *j* from i..n, it would be O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks. I thought that might be the case, but it didn't seem right. I suppose this case with 50,000 iterations has showed a limitation of Big O, because all constants are ignored.

Comment: @Tom, no, Big-O shows how the worst case scenario _scales_.  If you double the input size how will the algorithm run.  For an algorithm running in O(n^2) then the worst run time fourdoubles when you double the input.  The 50.000 loop cancels in that equation.

Comment: Is there any defined way of representing constants in a running time statement? e.g. O(n) + a constant?

Comment: @Tom, no, that's not the way O() works.  Think of it this way - given any sufficiently large number of items (n), we are interested in knowing how the running time increases as we e.g. double n.  For O(n^3) the running time multiply by eight  (since that is what (2n)^3/n^3 results in).  The "sufficiently large" clause means that everything else than the largest factor of n fades away.  This include constants and lesser factors of n.  Think of n being a trillion or more.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. You are just adding four loops which is `O(N)`. So it is `4O(N)`, then it is multiplied by `50, 000` which is a large number but it is not `N` dependent.

Answer (score 0):

This is O(N). But in this context, depending on what you have for N, the constant might have a big impact on the performance of your algorithm.